# How to disable Switch User option from Fedora 15

Tags: fedora, users, screen-lock

Is there a way to disable the **Switch User** option from a locked screen on Fedora 15? I've tried [this](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/272/how-to-define-gdm-login-banner-disable-user-list) way, but no luck, since `gconf-editor` has no effect.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to disable this option?

Comment: @jofel others can shutdown the machine or log in while I have it locked.

Comment: Shutdown is usually forbidden by polkit if more than one user is logged in. And as Linux is a multi-user system, there should be no (security) problem, if multiple users are logged in.

Comment: But if someone logs in as root and runs or sudos a shutdown command, won't that override the multiple user restriction?

Comment: @FloppyDisk It doesn't matter if root does it. My concern is about anybody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 ways of doing this. Both involve [XScreenSaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/). 
Either deactivate or uninstall `gnome-screensaver` and start the `XScreenSaver` (install if needed), or switch to [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/) which is using it. 
`XScreenSaver` can easily be controlled and configured to disable the switch user feature.